# Multi-project organization with Bower, Grunt, Angular

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bower

I'm starting a set of projects and am not sure how I should organize them, or what the workflow is for this scenario.

I have one "common" project with some common JS code (common UI controls, logic, etc.), and two other application projects that each use this common project.

I'm using ng-boilerplate as a basis for these applications, and am trying to create a build process for each of the two application projects that first builds the "common" stuff, pulls that in to the project, then builds the application project with the common stuff.

Is this something Grunt can do? Or should I be looking at a low-tech solution like a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved something similar by turning my common code into a package that is used by all the other dependent projects. In my case I was using Node.JS so I turned it into a CommonJS package and linked that package into my other projects.

It's not really Grunt territory, but it definitely becomes useful when project reach this level of complexity.

Comment: How did you "link" the package into your other projects?

Comment: Using ```npm link``` you can link a package in a local folder to your current project so that it may installed with ```npm install``` as a dependency specified in your ```package.json``` file.